# Stop popup warnings that cover my editor in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to turn off Android Studio's pop up warnings. The lightbulbs on the side of the screen are fine. THESE messages are covering entire lines of code. I can move my mouse cursor to make them disappear, but they reappear only a few keystrokes later. I never have more than one on the screen at a time. Mine are blue with white text, but I have changed my appearance settings so they might look different than yours. (I used the Darcula theme as my base)

As I am editing my code, Android Studio pops up little thought bubbles that tell me things like: "? android.content.Context?"

"Yes IDE, I know I haven't imported it yet, I don't need to be reminded and I'd like to see the code on the line above it, but you're covering it up with you giant warning message..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Settings | Editor | Auto Import | [x] Add unambiguous imports on the fly.

If you don't like this behavior, you can turn off the auto import entirely: Settings | Editor | Auto Import | Java | [ ] Show import popup